# Why is SvnAnt still trying to connect to my old repository IP address?

Tags: linux, ant, centos, svnant

I know just enough about Ant and SvnAnt to be dangerous. I put together the build.xml and .properties files a while back, and now that I'm running into issues I'm out of my league I fear.

Simple scenario.  I have an SvnAnt task that would update code from a remote repository.  Worked great.  Recently the IP address of that repository changed, so I opened up my build.properties file and changed the IP address accordingly:

```
svnant.project.url=http://my.new.ip.here/svn/project/trunk
```

Problem is, when I run ant and specify the update target *SvnAnt is still trying to hit the old IP*.  I went so far as to throw this in my build.xml file, under the corresponding task:

```
<echo message="${line.separator}Updating working copy from ${svnant.project.url}" />
```

And sure enough, when I run the ant task I see the message:

```
update:
 [echo]
 [echo] Updating working copy from http://my.new.ip.here/svn/project/trunk
...
```

But this task always errors out after a minute or so with this error:

```
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/project/trunk'
svn: PROPFIND of '/svn/project/trunk': could not connect to server (http://OLD.FREAKING.IP.HERE)
```

Note the **OLD.FREAKING.IP.HERE** part.

So my question is: why is Ant/SvnAnt still trying to connect to my old IP?

I've restarted Apache. Nothing of interest in /etc/hosts.

Thanks

**edit: CentOS release 5.2**

Comment: Sounds like you need to do an svn relocate: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html

Comment: Thanks martin, spot-on.  Sometimes can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that your existing working copy has meta information (`.svn` folder), which refers to the old ip address.  Since you are updating and not checking out, this is used.